# nginx unknown directive "keepalive"

Tags: nginx

I am using the following configuration

```
upstream site {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    error_page 400 404 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location  /50x.html {
            internal;
            root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    location /static {
        root /opt/site/static;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass         http://site;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```

I have saved it to /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.conf and symlinked to it /etc/sites-enabled/site.conf , and when I restart nginx it gives me the following error:

`Restarting nginx: [emerg]: unknown directive "keepalive" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf:3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `keepalive` directive. Use `keepalive_timeout` instead. And you can't put it inside `upsream`, use inside `http`, `server` or `location`.

Comment: Thanks! It still exists on the nginx site though.

Answer (score 0):

Option "keepalive" is provided by [keepalive module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamKeepaliveModule). And since 1.1.4 keepalive functionality is included in the main code.

Comment: You are mixing two things - that module is configuring keepalive for connections to the upstream proxy, not for incoming connections from clients.